# CoreData crashed on insertion and deletion happens simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm facing CoreData crash on FetchedResultsController.

**Scenario:** I'm trying to insert and remove some data simultaneously on FetchedResultsController. So, during this time the crash happening unexpectedly.

*Note:* The crash happens rarely.

I have tried some answers from StackOverflow but none of them worked for me. So, it would be helpful to get a solution to this issue.

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
 
 switch type {
 
 case .insert:
 guard let newIndexPath = newIndexPath  else { return }
 self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: rowAnimation)
 
 case .delete:
 guard let indexPath = indexPath else { return }
 self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
 
 case .update:
 guard let indexPath = indexPath else { return }
 self.updateRow(atIndexpath: indexPath)
 
 case .move:

 guard let deleteIndexPath = indexPath, let insertIndexPath = newIndexPath, deleteIndexPath == insertIndexPath else {
    return
 }
 self.updateRow(atIndexpath: insertIndexPath)
 }
}
```

Crash Report:

> *** Assertion failure in -[AppName.tableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore/UIKit-3698.119.2/UITableView.m:1821
>
> [error] fault: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 7.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

I have got some clue on this issue, it's happening in `tableView.endUpdates()` in `controllerDidChangeContent` delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You are not *moving* anything in the `.move` case. There is an API:

```
case .move: tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
```

The force unwrapped paths are safe because the controller sends both paths in the `.move` case as well as the appropriate paths in the other cases.

Comment: I have tried your answer but it seems doesn't work for me. I have updated my crash report and added some clue on this issue. So, can you check it once again.

Comment: Normally it must not happen but under certain circumstances for example you change properties simultaneously which affect the sorting it could happen

Answer (score 0):

By the crash message you provided, it seems like the crash happens when there's an insertion, but table view still has an old number of rows.

As written in Apple's documentation it is recommended that you perform a series of table view changes nested in-between `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` method calls.

This will allow table view to synchronise the data by calling

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

methods, etc.

Thus, what you could do is to add `tableView.beginUpdates(), tableView.endUpdates()` calls in NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate's method implementations

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Also you are not handling `.move` case properly. `tableView.moveRow(at: oldIndexPath, to: newIndexPath)` should be called instead

Comment: we have added the beginUpdates() and endUpdates() but sorry I have not included here. Also, my question is, the move will call only when we move the cell from one place to other places right.

Comment: Yes, move should be called when you rearrange table view cells. Also, if you don't really care about animations you can just call `tableView.reloadData()` in `func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?)` and the crash should not happen again

Comment: I have tried by changing the move with insertion and deletion but still, it's happening.  Also, I have updated my crash report. Can you please check it.

Comment: Also, one clue which I got is, it's happening in tableView.endUpdates() in controllerDidChangeContent delegate.